# Does NM=I give MN=I?

Tags: linear-algebra

I read the following statement in a exercise, which I don't think is correct:

$NM=I \rightarrow MN=I$, where $M,N$ are real square matrix of finite size.

However, I cannot think of a counter-example to this.

Comment: @MathLover  There is no such condition given so that N or M is invertible tho

Comment: Left multiply by $N^{-1}$ and then right multiply by N.

Comment: By definition, $N$ is invertible; now multiply by $N^{-1}$ on the LHS and $N$ on the RHS of both equations.

Comment: Oh yeah det(M)*det(N)=1

Comment: @MathLover Clearly. However, this is about proving that there is such a thing as "the" inverse, and not separate left inverse and right inverse.

Comment: The reason it is hard to prove is that it isn't true for "infinite" square matrices.

Comment: Yes, via the invertible matrix theorem.  For $M$ if $MN =I$ then $N$ is unique in doing so and $NM = I$.  http://mathworld.wolfram.com/InvertibleMatrixTheorem.html

Comment: ^Learning the proof of (relevant parts of) this theorem will answer the OP's question.